# Two pages back on window.history.back();

Tags: javascript, forms

I have an order form at domain.com/order/form.html, when filling in this form you get taken to the next part of the form at `domain.com/order/form.html#step2`. This going-forward goes fine but there is a 'Back' button on there with an `onclick="window.history.back();return false;"`.

The problem is that this doesn't take me back to the `domain.com/order/form.html` but to the domain.com page (the page before going to the first part of the order form). It happens in all browsers and I have no clue what a fix is.

If you need any info, please ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the form is ajaxed and only the hash is changed.

If you want to go back to the form, change the url for example

```
location=location.href.split("#")[1]
```

or

```
var loc = location.href;
var step = parseInt(location.hash.replace("#step",""),10); 
if (step && step > 1) {
  step--;
  location.hash = "#step"+step;
}
```